# Пробелы между словами php

Tags: php

Есть предложение вида:

ICPO - аббревиатура, а полное InternationalCriminalPoliceOrganization.

Нужно отличать аббревиатуру от слов, между которыми нужно вставить пробел. Пробовал так

```
ltrim(preg_replace( '/[А-ЯA-Z]/u', ' $0', $text));
```

Но это также ставит пробелы между буквами аббревиатуры, что недопустимо.

Возможно ли это ?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ.

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zа-я])(?=[A-ZА-Я])/u', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]